# Check for Enter value in string

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, return-value

I have a string that is = textarea.value

```
var str = "one
two
three"
```

If I loop through the string, what is the value of the Enter key?

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] === '????') {   
    console.log('found enter key')
  };
};
```

note: I know how to check when the enter key is pressed inside the textarea, I would like to check for it using the string.

Comment: You mean a newline?

Comment: It's called a *line break*. "Enter" is the name of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe search for `\n\` or `\r` (or even `\r\n`):

```js
var str = document.getElementById('text').value;
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] === '\n' || str[i] === '\r') {
    console.log('found enter key')
  };
};
```

```html
<textarea id="text"> "one
two
three"</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try '\n' if you want to check for new lines. Since pressing Enter, it creates a new line, I think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, the "enter" key is actually two characters. **carriage return** `'\r'` and **line feed** or **newline** `'\n'`. You could loop and check for just line feed/newline or check in pairs:

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
  if (str[i] === '\r' && str[i + 1] === '\n') {   
    console.log('found enter key at pos ' + i + ' and ' + (i + 1))
  };
};
```

Additionally you could just use [*string*.indexOf(*searchValue*,*startPos*)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

`str.indexOf("\r\n")`